# CakePHP 3.x - why write a query if it's not actually required?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In the (incredibly confusing) documentation for CakePHP 3.x it gives the following under the [New ORM Upgrade Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html):

> You can decorate queries with iterators and call methods without even touching the database. This is great when you have parts of your view cached and having the results taken from the database is not actually required:

```
// No queries made in this example!
$results = $articles->find()
->order(['title' => 'DESC'])
->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    return $results->extract('title');
});
```

Why would you have the code above *at all*, if "having the results taken from the database is not actually required"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to read that in the context that it is embedded in, the whole section is about how "*calling `find` on a table will not return the results immediately, but will return a Query object*", and in what situations that can be useful.

Query objects do not automatically generate and run SQL, they only do so when explicitly invoking specific methods like `toArray()`, `all()`, collection methods, etc, or when iterating the object.

The situation described there is when the part of your code where the query object is finally being executed, ie the actual SQL query is being constructed and run, has been cached (for example a view template), so that running the query again on subsequent requests would be pointless and would just produce unnecessary overhead, as you already have the cached results.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Rows From A Table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > How Are Queries Lazily Evaluated](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated)**

Comment: Hmm. I understand what you've said but I think the documentation for 3.x is written in an incredibly poor manner. It's very unclear to an average reader what that means. I don't know why the documentation for 3.x is so bad because for 2.x it was actually very good!

Comment: @Andy Well, the 2.x docs had something like 4 or 5 years more to evolve, that may be one of the reasons. If you have any ideas how the docs could be made better, please create a ticket [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues), or maybe even add changes yourself if you can, help is always welcome!

Comment: This is a code smell. The documentation is describing **pass through** execution of the controller action. The *query* object is created and forwarded to the template where it will be *lazy* executed, but if the view is cached this *lazy* execution never happens. The problem here is that this behavior *obfuscates* the *optimization* of the code. There is no indication anywhere that this is happening. If you do this. Name your variables as **$articleQuery** so that it is very clear you intend to always pass a query to the view.